# Como criar um mini banco de dados escrito em php usando um arquivo de texto no formato de json

Tags: php, json

Eu estava precisando de um mini banco de dados pessoal escrito em PHP para armazenas alguns dados internos do meu site, onde eu criaria novas propriedades, mudaria elas e excluiria posteriormente caso necessário.

No exemplo abaixo mostra como seria esse arquivo .txt e como buscar/mudar um valor específico (no caso mudar o valor offline da Mariana para online) no JSON.

config.txt

```
{
   "users": {
      "Mariana": "offline",
      "João": "online"
   }
}
```

storage.php:

```
$method = "[GET ou SET]";
$string = "users/mariana"; // Caminho para a propriedade
$data = file_get_contents("config.txt");

$json = json_decode( $data, true ); // Transforma do JSON em array
$path = explode( "/", $string );
$last = "";

foreach ( $path as $value ) {
    $last = $json[$value]; // Navegar nas propriedades do JSON até a Mariana
}


if ( $method == "SET" ) {
    // Mudar um valor da propriedade
    $last = "online";
    file_put_contents("cofing.txt", $json); // Sava o novo arquvio

    echo "saved";
} else if ( $method == "GET" ) {
    // Somente exibir o valor da propriedade 

    echo $last;
}
```

Não sou tão especialista em PHP mas se o código fosse em JavaScript funcionaria, mas prefiro em PHP para ser rápido e não da conflito quando vários usuários tentarem mudar algum valor do config.txt.
Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Está fazendo a navegação para o elemento errada... Está pegando apenas o primeiro nível dos índices, precisa de uma função recursiva para cada vez descer um nível... Estou sem tempo pra fazer agora, talvez amanhã...

Comment: Aaa verdade, não tinha percebido =o obrigado

Comment: Eita mas depois que executar o loop, não vai mais salvar no final quando coloca no arquivo

Comment: Só uma pergunta: vc faz isso pq não sabe a existencia do sqlite ou pq o contexto que vc se encontra só permite fazer em arquivo/json?

Comment: Não gosto do formato de tabela desses banco de dados e acho que se fosse em formato de árvore em Json seria melhor =)

Comment: @IagoBruno adicionei a resposta.

Comment: Existe também outras alternativas melhores para fazer isso que um arquivo .txt. Essa abordagem ainda tem problemas de acesso simultâneo caso varias requisições rodem ao mesmo tempo. Como alternativa podes armazenar com Redis, mencached que usam um conjunto de key -> value ou MongoDB.

Comment: Além da possibilidade do uso do NoSQL, você ainda pode usar o tipo JSON do PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabalhar com esse tipo de funcionalidade, uma função recursiva é o jeito mais fácil de faze-lo, exemplo:

#### Arquivo JSON:

```
{
   "users": {
      "mariana": "offline",
      "joao": "online"
   }
}
```

#### Função PHP

```
function JSONDB($path, $method, $data, &$value = NULL){

   // Separa todas as chaves
   $path = explode('/', $path); 

   // Salva a primeira na variável $key e remove-a da variável $path
   $key = array_shift($path); 

   // Junta todas as chaves em um novo path
   $npath = implode('/', $path);

   // Verifica se é GET e está na última chave
   if ($method == 'GET' && count($path) === 0)
      // Adiciona o valor na variável assinada $value
      $value = $data[$key]; 

   // Verifica se é SET e está na última chave
   else if ($method == 'SET' && count($path) === 0)
      // Seta o valor na chave atual
      $data[$key] = $value; 

   // Verifica se a chave atual não está vazia e é um array
   else if (!empty($data[$key]) && is_array($data[$key]))
      // Desce um nivel no array passando $data[$key] e atualiza o retorno na chave
      $data[$key] = JSONDB($npath, $method, $data[$key], $value); 

   // Nenhuma condição satisfeita, erro (provavelmente caminho errado)
   // Ou dados incorretos
   else 
      // Nada a fazer por aqui
      $value = FALSE; 

   // Retorna os dados para serem salvos
   return $data;
}
```

#### Uso

```
// Arquivo com os dados JSON
$file = 'ususarios.json';

// Define método [GET ou SET]
$method = 'SET';

// Caminho para a propriedade
// IMPORTANTE> JSON é Case Sensitive ou seja, diferencia maiúscula de minúscula
// o caminho deve ser escrito da mesma forma como está no arquivo separados por /
$path = 'users/mariana'; 

// Valor a ser alterado caso o método seja GET
// Caso o método seja GET o retorno será colocado nessa variável, 
// então basta definir a variável e passa-la no quarto parâmetro
$val = 'online';

// Pega os dados do json
$data = file_get_contents($file);

// Transforma do JSON em array
$json = json_decode( $data, true ); 

// Executa a função recursiva, todos os dados serão retornado
// caso o método seja GET o valor será colocado na variável do quarto parâmetro
$dados = JSONDB($path, $method, $json, $val);

// Salva caso seja SET
if ($method == 'SET')
   $salva = file_put_contents("cofing.txt", json_encode($dados));

// Imprimindo os dados

echo '<style>pre{display:block; width:80%; margin: 20px auto;padding:10px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.06);border-radius:5px;box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}</style>';
echo '<pre>';
if ( $method == 'SET' ) {
    echo $salvo ? 'Arquivo salvo...' : 'Erro ao salvar...';
} else {
    // Somente exibir o valor da propriedade 
    // Obs, a variável $val é o quarto parâmetro passado na função
    // que quando o método for GET, será onde o retorno do GET será armazenado
    var_dump( $val );
}
echo '</pre>';

// Todos os dados
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($dados);
echo '</pre>';
```

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado do script]

#### Observações:

Essa forma de trabalhar com dados é bem primitiva, ou seja, estou dando apenas o passo inicial para que a partir daqui você possa construir sua classe com métodos de validação de entrada e saída de dados, validação de escrita de arquivo e etc.

Esse tipo de funcionalidade é bem útil para guardar configurações como de conexão com o banco de dados e etc. (Mas é claro que o arquivo deve estar protegido contra acesso externo.

Comment: Nossa, bem completo e diferente do que eu tinha pensando, obrigado! Vou testar depois mas Acho que vai funcionar do jeito que eu queria com alguns alterações =D

Comment: Seria dessa forma que o MongoDB salva os dados?

Comment: Talvez, mas duvido muito @WallaceMaxters. Essa forma é muito simplória e como o [gmsantos comentou](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80697/como-criar-um-mini-banco-de-dados-escrito-em-php-usando-um-arquivo-de-texto-no-f#comment164177_80697) na pergunta, aqui não está implementando concorrência no arquivo e em caso de muitas requisições em algum momento ocorrerá um conflito.

Answer (score 2):

Seria algo mais ou menos assim?

**Config.json**

```
[  
   {  
      "nome":"Mariana",
      "status":"online"
   },
   {  
      "nome":"Joao",
      "status":"offline"
   },
   {  
      "nome":"Jose",
      "status":"online"
   }
]
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste JSON</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function botaoClick(botao){
        document.getElementById('status').value = botao;
        return true;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form action="storage.php" method="POST">
        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" />
        <input type="submit" value="online" onclick="return botaoClick(this.value)"/>
        <input type="submit" value="offline" onclick="return botaoClick(this.value)"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="SET" />
        <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**storage.php**

```
<?php

$metodo = isset($_POST['acao']) ? $_POST['acao'] : "";
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : "";
$status = isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : "";

$data = file_get_contents("config.json");

$json = json_decode($data);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
  if($value->nome == $nome){
    if($metodo == 'SET'){
        $value->status = $status;
        break;
    } else if ($metodo == 'GET') {
        echo $value->status;
        break;
    }
  }
}

$json_enc  = json_encode($json);

file_put_contents('config.json', $json_enc);

echo $json_enc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Acho que o ideal, e o mais seguro, seria você fazer uma cópia do arquivo do banco de dados e depois fazer as alterações necessárias nele. Portanto, recomendo que você utilize as próprias ferramentas fornecidas para gerenciar o banco de dados.

**Ex.:** Se você utiliza o [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) como banco de dados, você poderia usar o [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/index.php) como sistema gerenciador. Nesse caso, você teria diversas vantagens, como:

1. **Consistência:** Ao remover/adicionar/editar uma informação, essa informação seria atualizada autmaticamente em todos os campos e tabelas dependentes, garantindo que a informação seja consistente.
2. **Velocidade:** Todo banco de dados é desenvolvido para ser muito rápido, portanto, criar sua própria função/linguagem de consulta para fazer esse tipo de coisa seria perda de tempo.
3. **Praticidade:** Utilizando pequenas consultas SQL e [triggers](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatilho_(banco_de_dados)) você poderia realizar uma grande quantidade de ações de maneira rápida e muito mais eficiente.

Existem diversas outras vantagens em utilizar sistemas gerenciadores de banco de dados, essas são apenas algumas delas. Portanto, reforçando o que foi dito: **Se você quiser manipular os dados de um site, utilize um sistema gerenciador de banco de dados para isso.**